# Snappy UnsatisfiedLinkError happened while sending KAFKA message

Tags: java, apache-kafka, snappy

Here is stack trace:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no snappyjava in java.library.path
    at org.apache.kafka.common.record.CompressionType$3.wrapForOutput(CompressionType.java:83)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.record.MemoryRecordsBuilder.<init>(MemoryRecordsBuilder.java:130)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.record.MemoryRecordsBuilder.<init>(MemoryRecordsBuilder.java:166)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.record.MemoryRecords.builder(MemoryRecords.java:507)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.record.MemoryRecords.builder(MemoryRecords.java:489)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.record.MemoryRecords.builder(MemoryRecords.java:437)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.RecordAccumulator.recordsBuilder(RecordAccumulator.java:254)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.RecordAccumulator.append(RecordAccumulator.java:230)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:942)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:865)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.invokeAfterCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:135)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerAfterCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerAfterCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:936)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:782)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:152)))
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doDelete(FrameworkServlet.java:931)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no snappyjava in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.loadNativeLibrary(SnappyLoader.java:182)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.loadSnappyApi(SnappyLoader.java:154)
    at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.<clinit>(Snappy.java:47)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyOutputStream.<init>(SnappyOutputStream.java:99)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyOutputStream.<init>(SnappyOutputStream.java:91)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyOutputStream.<init>(SnappyOutputStream.java:81)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.record.CompressionType$3.wrapForOutput(CompressionType.java:81)
    ... 32 common frames omitted
```

What's confusing to me is that this error was found after the program had been running for a while, before that KAFKA messages were being sent successfully, and then suddenly this error occurred. When I recompiled the docker image to start running, the error disappeared again

I found a lot of snappy.so files under the /tmp directory with names like `snappy-1.1.7-1b59cb86-e360-4325-986c-e34b46c28789-libsnappyjava.so`

Although the program runs successfully now, I don't know when the error will happen again. I also don't know how to reproduce the problem